# turn.js hidden div element

Tags: javascript, html, css, turn.js

I'm currently working on the [Steve Jobs *turn.js*](http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/steve-jobs) sample like.

I'm having an issue adding content to the pages because many of the `div` elements I'm working with are ***hidden***.

So far I have tried to add content via *CSS* because I can see the hidden `div` elements when inspecting.
The problem is that I can't customise or add new classes to work with the pages.

I also tried commenting out the "hide canvas":

```
// Show canvas

    $('#canvas').css({
        visibility: ''
    });
}

// // Hide canvas

// $('#canvas').css({
//     visibility: 'hidden'
// });
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to work with the ***hidden*** `div` elements.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far. Please put your code in your question

Comment: edited and provided what i have tried

Comment: Thanks. Im no expert on turn.js, so Im not likely the one to help you. But visibility : '' is wrong. If you want to show it, set it to visibility : 'visible'

Comment: @OleHaugset, That's not the problem.  from http://api.jquery.com/css/: `Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. $( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" ) — removes that property from an element if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM manipulation of the style property.`